# Is the Ubuntu Landscape $0.01/hr pricing based on machine runtime?

Tags: landscape

When using Canonical's self-service Landscape 1c-per-hour service, how is the amount of hours calculated? I.e. My servers run around the clock, so obviously I would pay 24c per day for each of those. My POS systems are only switched on for ~8 hours a day, though.

My question is: Does Landscape only charge me for the amount of time that each managed machine was switched on, or does it assume every machine is used 24x7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Landscape SaaS counts managed hours. Hours where a machine are off should not count in the usage.